# two DataFrame plot in a single plot matplotlip

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot two DataFrame in a single plot.Though, I have seen similar post but none seems to work out.

First 5 rows of my dataframe looks like this:

df1

```
    name    type        start       stop    strand
0   geneA   transcript  2000        7764        +
1   geneA   exon        2700        5100        +
2   geneA   exon        6000        6800        +
3   geneB   transcript  9000        12720       -
4   geneB   exon        9900        10100       -
```

df2

```
    P1      P2       P3      P4
0   0.28    0.14    0.19    0.19
1   0.30    0.16    0.17    0.20
2   0.26    0.13    0.20    0.12
3   0.21    0.13    0.25    0.15
4   0.31    0.03    0.24    0.20
```

I want the plot to look like this:

[image: sample plot]

I tried doing this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

```
ax = df1.plot()

df1.plot(ax=ax)
```

but, the output was not meaningful.
I will appreciate suggestions/solutions on how to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is answerable in its current state. It is unclear how the data you've shown becomes the shown plot. Where does the variance come from in the line thickness? How are you processing variable ranges which overlap? How are you uniforming an x axis? etc etc.

Comment: @Henry,I am new to python and its plot libraries. from what i understand, the y-axis has df2 with the `strand` column of df1 and the x-axis has df1 with only `start `and `stop` columns.

Comment: But it's not quite that straight forward. Plotting requires plot _points_. For example `plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3])` would plot the line `y=x` from `[0, 3]`. You don't have plot points. You have intervals that would need to be somehow converted into _points_ that could be plotted. But you don't specify how you're handling overlapping ranges or even how ranges should be converted to points. Also line plots don't have jagged variance like the wave forms in the output. There's a _lot_ of work that would need to be done to get from the data to the specified plots.

Comment: like you said, i  think a lot need to be done! `df2` is linked to `+` and `-` values . but about the jagged variance, is what i dont understand

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68356625/16343464) for the basic plotting example. Please describe how your annotations work and how you would like to map them in the graph. Can you also provide a larger (or full) dataset? This will be nicer to have a working example.

Comment: You need a basic tutorial, which is off topic on SO. This is not a free coding site, do "a lot need to be done" likely means you're in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(df2.columns)+1, sharex=True, )

# plots for df2 columns
i = 0
for col in df2.columns:
    df2[col].plot(ax=axes[i])
    axes[i].set_ylim(0, 1.2)
    axes[i].set_ylabel(col)
    i+=1
    
## code to plot annotations
# axes[-1].plot(…)
axes[-1].set_xlabel('Genomic position')

# remove space between plots
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
```

[image: genomic plot]

Here is the full graph:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(df2.columns)+1, sharex=True, )

# plots for df2 columns
i = 0
for col in df2.columns:
    df2[col].plot(ax=axes[i], color='#505050')
    axes[i].set_ylim(0, 1.3)
    axes[i].set_ylabel(col)
    i+=1
    
## code to plot annotations
axes[-1].set_xlabel('Genomic position')
axes[-1].set_ylabel('annotations')
axes[-1].set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)
axes[-1].set_yticks([0, 1])
axes[-1].set_yticklabels(['−', '+'])

for _, r in df1.iterrows():
    marker = '|'
    lw=1
    if r['type'] == 'exon':
        marker=None
        lw=8
    y = 1 if r['strand'] == '+' else 0
    axes[-1].plot((r['start'], r['stop']), (y, y),
                  marker=marker, lw=lw,
                  solid_capstyle='butt',
                  color='#505050')
    
# remove space between plots
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
```

[image: genomic data]

Comment: @ mozway , your example yield almost exactly what i want. I only need to figure out how to get the 3 `box plots` at the bottom of the plot. Thank you!

Comment: See my comment on question. Can you provide the full datasets?

Comment: Link to a file?

Comment: I updated the graph, I'll let you try to find by yourself how to customize ticklabels and vertical lines ;)

Comment: @ mozway, wow! you are the best! . you made my day! Thanks. what does this command lw=lw imply?

Comment: The `lw`/`linewidth` option sets the line width. I used it to make the exons thicker. You will find a detailed list of parameters in the [matplotlib.pyplot.plot documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).

Comment: @ mozway, I want to reproduce another plot with same data. the plot is similar to the first one with difference in `plot for df2 dataframe code`. I tried to do some code modification but i keep getting errors. i will be glad if you can be of help again. here is a sample of the plot [ link ] (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vlbJYSk7EIXeBhUO-AYYvAqEz2NEzwZs?usp=sharing)

Comment: Then please open a new question, you can add there a link to this question and conversely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subplots` for doing so (since it is difficult to understand how the two df should be plotted I've provided a general example)

```py
Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,axes = plt.subplots(4,1) #4 rows, one column
for ax in axes:
   plt.plot(X1,y1 ax =ax) # loop over each subplot and create a plot
   plt.plot(X2,y2, ax = ax)
```

Comment: @CutPoison, where can i add `df1` and `df2` from the example? i used it in place of `x1` and `y1` but i got error