# two DataFrame plots

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a similar plot to the one answered in the link below:

[two DataFrame plot in a single plot matplotlip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356120/two-dataframe-plot-in-a-single-plot-matplotlip/68356625?noredirect=1#comment120837919_68356625)

I made some modification to `plots for df2 columns code block` because i think that is where i have to modify but i could not yield the output.
a sample of the plot i want is this [image]

this was how i modified it:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(signals.columns)+1, sharex=True, )
i = 0
for col in df2.columns:
    fig, axs = plt.subplots()
    sns.regplot(x='', y='', data=df2, ax=axs[0])
        df2[col].plot(ax=axes[i], color='grey')
        axes[i].set_ylabel(col)
        i+=1
I have seen that its wrong.
```

I tried this out, it seems like a head way :)

How do I make modification on this to get what i want:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(signals.columns)+1, sharex=True, )

# plots for df2 columns
i = 0
for col in df2.columns:
    lw=1
    df2[col].plot(ax=axes[i], color='grey')
    axes[i].set_ylim(0, 1)
    axes[i].set_ylabel(col)
sns.rugplot(df2["P1"])
```

Comment: Btw, how did you generate this graph? Is this for homework? If yes, you should try something by yourself.

Comment: The graph is from a learning platform. not a homework.

Comment: But the point is for you to learn, right? Can you post the code that you have tried to generate and the eventual errors?

Comment: this was what i tried: `f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(signals.columns)+1, sharex=True, )
i = 0
for col in df2.columns:
 fig, axs = plt.subplots()
 sns.regplot(x='', y='', data=df2, ax=axs[0])
     df2[col].plot(ax=axes[i], color='grey')
     axes[i].set_ylabel(col)
     i+=1`      i have seen that is absolutely wrong!

Comment: Please edit your question to post your code

Comment: You can try to use [seaborn.rugplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.rugplot.html)

Comment: am trying it out :) i will post whatever my result is. Thanks

Comment: You actually have many ways to achieve this, you can also use [matplotlib.pyploy.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) or [matplotlib.pyplot.axvline](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html)

Comment: I only have a little understanding of `seaborn.rugplot`. I can only use one variable in a dataFtrame compare to this case where i want to use the four variables. to put everything together to achieve the kind of plot i want is beyond my knowledge of python and the said libraries. I surfed the internet, but to no avail.

Comment: I provided you with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to make this graph. df1 and df2 are as defined in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356120/two-dataframe-plot-in-a-single-plot-matplotlip/68356625)

The version with [matplotlib.pyplot.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) is faster to draw, but less faithful to the example. The version with [seaborn.rugplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.rugplot.html) looks identical to the example, but takes longer to draw. I highlighted the important part of the code between comment lines `########`

### using [matplotlib.pyplot.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(df2.columns)+1, sharex=True,
                       gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':np.append(np.repeat(1, len(df2.columns)), 3)})

####### variable part below #######

# plots for df2 columns
i = 0
for col in df2.columns:
    axes[i].scatter(x=df2.index, y=np.repeat(0, len(df2)), c=df2[col], marker='|', cmap='Greys')
    axes[i].set_ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
    axes[i].set_yticks([0])
    axes[i].set_yticklabels([col])
    i+=1
    
###################################

## code to plot annotations
axes[-1].set_xlabel('Genomic position')
axes[-1].set_ylabel('annotations')
axes[-1].set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)
axes[-1].set_yticks([0, 1])
axes[-1].set_yticklabels(['−', '+'])

for _, r in df1.iterrows():
    marker = '|'
    lw=1
    if r['type'] == 'exon':
        marker=None
        lw=8
    y = 1 if r['strand'] == '+' else 0
    axes[-1].plot((r['start'], r['stop']), (y, y),
                  marker=marker, lw=lw,
                  solid_capstyle='butt',
                  color='#505050')
    
# remove space between plots
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

axes[-1].set_xlim(0, len(df2))

f.set_size_inches(6, 2)
```

[image: genomic data plot using matplotlib scatter]

### using [seaborn.rugplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.rugplot.html)

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(df2.columns)+1, sharex=True,
                       gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':np.append(np.repeat(1, len(df2.columns)), 3)})

####### variable part below #######

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cm as cm
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1, clip=True)
mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.Greys)

# plots for df2 columns
i = 0
for col in df2.columns:
    sns.rugplot(x=df2.index, color=list(map(mapper.to_rgba, df2[col])), height=1, ax=axes[i])
    axes[i].set_yticks([0])
    axes[i].set_yticklabels([col])
    i+=1

###################################
    
## code to plot annotations
axes[-1].set_xlabel('Genomic position')
axes[-1].set_ylabel('annotations')
axes[-1].set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)
axes[-1].set_yticks([0, 1])
axes[-1].set_yticklabels(['−', '+'])

for _, r in df1.iterrows():
    marker = '|'
    lw=1
    if r['type'] == 'exon':
        marker=None
        lw=8
    y = 1 if r['strand'] == '+' else 0
    axes[-1].plot((r['start'], r['stop']), (y, y),
                  marker=marker, lw=lw,
                  solid_capstyle='butt',
                  color='#505050')
    
# remove space between plots
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

axes[-1].set_xlim(0, len(df2))

f.set_size_inches(6, 2)
```

[image: genomic data plot with seaborn rugplot]